# React Native Tab Navigator within Stack Navigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-firebase

I have the following Stack Navigator in App.js:

```
return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator  initialRouteName="Login" screenOptions={{headerShown:false}}>
        {user ? (
          <>
            <Stack.Screen name="Home">
              {(props) => <HomeScreen {...props} extraData={user} />}
            </Stack.Screen>
            <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
            
          </>
        ) : (
          <>
            <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Registration" component={RegistrationScreen} />
          </>
        )}
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
```

I want to add a bottom tab navigator that shows up on the HomeScreen, and allows me to go back and forth between the HomeScreen and ProfileScreen. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this is to create a tab navigator component where `Home` and `Profile` are 2 screens of the navigator:

```
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

function TabNavigator({route}) {
  // Retrieve user from initalParams.
  // The user is passed to initialParams in the snippet below.
  const user = route.params?.user
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}
```

Then the tab navigator can be a screen of your stack navigator:

```
return (
  <NavigationContainer>
    <Stack.Navigator
      initialRouteName="Login"
      screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
      {user ? (
        <>
          <Stack.Screen name="Tabs" component={TabNavigator} initialParams={{user: user}}/>
        </>
      ) : (
        <>
          <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Registration" component={RegistrationScreen} />
        </>
      )}
    </Stack.Navigator>
  </NavigationContainer>
);
```

If you need access to `user` from inside `HomeScreen` you can pass it using down using `initialParams` the same way it was passed down to the `TabNavigator`. If you don't want to keep passing stuff down like this you could try the Context api.

---

I removed the `Login` screen in the above example, because I assumed this was a mistake as you already have a `Login` screen defined for when you don't have an authenticated user.